# Как реализовать кнопку "Удалить" на Django?

Tags: html, веб-программирование, django

Я делаю простейшую тудушечку. Нужна помощь в реализации удаления выполненных задач.

Пользователь на странице удаляет задачу. Он нажимает кнопку "delete" и задача исчезает. Я хз, как это реализовать, поэтому прошу скинуть готовое решение или где можно прочитать про реализацию списка задач на Django.

Заранее спасибо.

Моя код:

*models.py*

```py
    from django.db import models

    class Task (models.Model):
        # Task in this app.
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

*views.py*

```py
    from django.shortcuts import render

    from .models import Task

    # Home page.
    def index(request):
        tasks = Task.objects.order_by('date_added')
        context = {'tasks': tasks}

        return render(request, 'work_list/index.html', context)

    # Delete your task.
    def delete_task(request, task_id):
        task = Task.objects.get(id=task_id)
        task.objects.delete()

        tasks = Task.objects.order_by('date_added')
        context = {'tasks': tasks}
        return render(request, 'work_list/index.html', context)
```

*urls.py*

```py
    # URL for work_list.

    from django.urls import path

    from . import views

    app_name = 'work_list'

    urlpatterns = [
        # Home page.
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
        ]
```

*index.html*

```html
    <h1>Best list ToDo</h1>
    <h2>You`re tasks:</h2>

    <ul>
        {% for task in tasks %}

            <li>
                {{ task }} 
            </li>
        {% empty %}
            <p>You haven`t actually task.</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Comment: С чем именно у Вас возникли сложности?

Comment: Вижу в вашем коде `task.objects.delete()` — то есть описанная в вопроса задача успешно решена. В чём у вас трудности, непонятно

Comment: Я не знаю, как это реализовать в html

Answer (score 1):

1. Вам необходимо в urls.py создать URL для вашего вью `delete_task`.
2. В html шаблоне сделать ссылку на этот URL, например, так: `<a href="{% url  'delete' 1 %}">
       Удалить </a>` - При переходе по ссылке будет выполнен код из `delete_task`, и задача с `id=1` будет удалена. Вместо 1 можете вставлять любой id через js, например.